# Any Azure DevOps API to get the value of Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate for any work item

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-boards

Any Azure DevOps API to get the value of Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate for any/all work items in a sprint.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute Custom Query using VSO/VSTS Rest API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36420030/how-to-execute-custom-query-using-vso-vsts-rest-api)

Comment: To get workItems with OriginalEstimate in one project, `workItems-Get/Get batch/list` is enough. But if what you want is to get workitem in a **specific sprint**, you need to use `Query By wiql`. So you need to use both these two APIs to get what you want.

Comment: Hi friend, any update for this issue? Can my answer helps to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any Azure DevOps API to get the value of
> Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate for any/all work items in a
> sprint.

Since you're trying to get workItems with `Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate` for specific items in specific spring, you have to combine the usage of `WorkItems-Get/Get batch/List` and `Query by WIQL`.

**Here're APIs that can return the `Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate` with given Ids:**

1.We can use [Get Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to get details about one specific work item, the response would contain the info about `OriginalEstimate`.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=6.1-preview.3
```

[image]

2.We can use [Get Work Items Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/get%20work%20items%20batch?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) to get list of work items based on ids, and we can customize the response based on request body:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitemsbatch?api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

**Request Body:**

```
{
  "ids": [
    124,
    125
  ],
  "fields": [
    "System.Id",
    "System.Title",
    "System.WorkItemType",
    "Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate"
  ]
}
```

3.[Work Items - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) can be used to list all or specific workitems with specified fields:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems?ids={ids}&fields=System.Id,System.Title,System.WorkItemType,Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate&api-version=6.1-preview.3
```

Both `Get Work Items Batch` and `Work Items-List` can return the workitems with value of `Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.OriginalEstimate`. The difference is that `Get Work Items Batch` uses `Post` and define IDs in request body while `Work Items-List` uses `Get` and define the IDs as URI parameters.

**Here's API to get workItem id based on WIQL:**

[Query By Wiql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/wiql/query%20by%20wiql?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1) can return the work Item Ids for specific sprint:

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=6.1-preview.2
```

**Request Body:**

```
{
  "query": "Select [System.Id] From WorkItems Where [System.TeamProject] = @project AND [System.IterationPath]= 'YourIterationPath'"
}
```

[image: If your IterationPath is a child]

If your `IterationPath` has such structure, the `YourIterationPath` above should be replaced with `CommonTests` or `CommonTests\\Iteration 1` depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

To access an API with its relations, you must use the following URL:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=5.1&$expand=relations
```

The parameter in the URL, `$expand=relations`, is mandatory to retrieve relations.